# Reset Form on Boostrap modal close event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So i have a data table that you can select a row and it gets the data from the table and puts it into a form thats in a modal all of that works but when i close the modal i wanna reset the form.

```
$('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    // reset form
    $('#user_form').trigger('reset');
});
```

but when i close the modal the form isnt reset.

demo - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjggYo

Comment: `reset` is not an `event`, it is a method. Did you try  `$('#user_form')[0].reset();` ?

Comment: @DavidDomain, yes i did and it dint do any thing

Comment: I've just tested it with your codepen, open the dev tools, select a row, click "Edit selection", inspect one of the form input elements with the dev tools and close the modal window. You will see the value from the inspected form input element will be cleared. The problem is that you are refilling the form input elements, every time when `shown.bs.modal` is fired.

Comment: ok and why is it when you click on the add button after you closed the modal the data is still there ?

Comment: I have just edited the above comment. You are refilling the form input elements whenever `show.bs.modal` is fired.

Comment: @DavidDomainso ow i see what i did thx mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not need `shown.bs.modal` event to show data in modal.

Pleas try after removing this event.

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () { }
```

And edit this :

```
$(this).find('input').each(function (index) {
```

To this:

```
$('.modal').find('input').each(function (index) {
```

Comment: yeah i looked over that :s and isnt it better to use `$('form#user_form').find('input').each(function (index) {` to make it form specific ?

Comment: @NicolaiVdS yes. Being specific with selector is more preferable. You should use  $('form#user_form')‌ selector.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need to reset the form? If the form is populated each time a row is selected, then the form in the modal will always show the relevant data from the selected row.

The way I deal with these situations is to use AngularsJS's data binding to manage data in forms. In order to reset a form, you simply reset the associated model in the Angular Controller.

```
$scope.myModel = {}
```

Comment: the reason i need to reset the form each time is you can add a new 'user' and edit one in the same form.